# client for remote JMS queue

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, glassfish-3

I have a JMS queue configured on remote glassfish server. I'm trying to connect this queue from my local machine. Is it possible to connect directly to this server or I need to connect via some broker/agent? How does it work? (I'm fresh in jms area)
Many thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your client application is running outside Glassfish here is a simple code example for an open mq client.

To get it to work you will need to reference 2 openmq jars from the glassfishInstall/mq/lib directory - imq.jar and jms.jar

```
import com.sun.messaging.ConnectionConfiguration;
import com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory;
import com.sun.messaging.Queue;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;

public class TestJmsClientStandalone2 {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws JMSException
    {
        ConnectionFactory connFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connFactory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqAddressList, "remotehostip:7676");

        Queue myQueue = new Queue("myRemoteQueue");

        try (Connection connection = connFactory.createConnection(); 
                Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); 
                MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(myQueue)) {

            Message message = session.createTextMessage("this is my test message");
            producer.send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Is your client application running in a local glassfish instance and trying to connect to remote glassfish instance's JMS resources?

If yes then I've found 2 ways to do this.  For both options set up the same connection factory and destination (queue) JMS Resources in the remote and local glassfish instances.

**1)** Set the jms connection factory property "addressList"

In the clients glassfish admin console go to `Resources->JMS Resources->Connection Factories->jms/YourConnectionFactory->Additional Properties`

Add an additional property with the name **addressList** and value **XX.XX.XX.XX:YYYY** 
where the value is the IP address of the remote machine and port number which the JMS service is running on.

or

**2)** Set the client glassfish Java Message Service to connect to the remote glassfish

In the clients glassfish admin console go to`Configurations->server-config->Java Message Service`

- Set JMS Service Type: REMOTE (click save)
- Set JMS `Hosts->default_JMS_host` IP Address and port to be the IP Address and port of the remote glassfish JMS service

I have tested both options to work with Glassfish 4.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I have no experience with Glassfish, but this scenario does work with JBoss (which integrates JBossMQ), and it should be generally applicable as well:

Server:

- Server configuration: Create the queue, and bind it to a name to be visible in JNDI
- Server configuration: Make sure that the connection factory is visible in JNDI as well

Client:

- Lookup both the connection factory and the queue using JNDI. This possibly requires some values to be put into the properties for the `InitialContext`
- On top of the connection factory and the queue, you can build the other objects (queue connection/session/receiver).

As for JBoss it looks like this:

```
    final Properties initialContextProperties = new Properties();
    initialContextProperties.put("java.naming.factory.initial",
            "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    initialContextProperties.put("java.naming.provider.url",
            "jnp://localhost:1099");

    //

    final InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(initialContextProperties);

    final QueueConnectionFactory qcf = (QueueConnectionFactory) ic
            .lookup("XAConnectionFactory");
    final Queue queue = (Queue) ic.lookup("queue/A");
```

So the broker/agent to go through is JNDI.