# Sending message to Remote JMS queue in glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, remote-server

I have a question. I have 2 servers which have connection to each other and have an applications to send and recieve messeges into JMS queue. But despite everything written here [client for remote JMS queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276176/client-for-remote-jms-queue) I can't send message from one server to another, it is either goes back to same server or not being displayed anywhere.
Here is the code which I use to send message, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?:

```
com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory connFactory = new com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory();
connFactory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqAddressList, "10.241.5.51:7676");
com.sun.messaging.Queue     queue = new com.sun.messaging.Queue("jms/tQueue");//(com.sun.messaging.Queue)client.lookup("jms/tQueue");
try (Connection connection = connFactory.createConnection();
      Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue)) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("It is a message from main class " + ": " + i);
      System.out.println("It come from main class:" + message.getText());
      producer.send(message);
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I got lost in terminology or something.
That code was working, only the other server should've been sending messages.